# Show/Hide div based on combination of selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

So I'm working on a website and have no clue where to start for the jquery.

There are 2 forms, one with 2 radio buttons, and the other with 5 radio buttons. There are 10 different combinations of shirts and pants that can be shown, but only one at a time depending on the combination of radio buttons they have selected.

So lets say that shirt 1 is red and shirt 2 is blue. Pants 1 is red, pants 2 is blue, pants 3 is green, and so on.

So img11.jpg would be a red shirt and red pants.

Img12.jpg is going to be red shirt and blue pants.

img21.jpg is blue shirt and red pants.

Img23.jpg is blue shirt and green pants.

(I've included a diagram to show this better)!

And so on and so forth. Anyone have any good links or would like to help make this possible?

I don't have much (if any) experience in javascript or jQuery, but here is my HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="shirt_Red" name="shirt" value="Red" />
    <input type="radio" id="shirt_Blue" name="shirt" value="Blue" />
</form

<form>
    <input type="radio" id="pants_Red" name="pants" value="Red" />
    <input type="radio" id="pants_Blue" name="pants" value="Blue" />
    <input type="radio" id="pants_Green" name="pants" value="Green" />
    <input type="radio" id="pants_Purple" name="pants" value="Purple" />
    <input type="radio" id="pants_Pink" name="pants" value="Pink" />
</form>
```

I'm not even sure if I would use image tags or a background for a div to do this, depending on how it works out with the jQuery or javascript. 
Thanks!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fIVHet1.png This is the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to handle every radio change event in your page

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change",function(ev){
     ... 
});
```

This function will be called whenever the user changes radio selection.

The next thing you need to consider is how to get which options are selected, you can use ':checked' inside your jQuery selector

```
var $shirt = $('input[name="shirt"]:checked');
var $pants = $('input[name="pants"]:checked');
```

Since your image file has numbered order, I would suggest you to put radio values in those number instead of color strings, for example:

```
<input type="radio" id="shirt_Red" name="shirt" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="shirt_Blue" name="shirt" value="2" />

<input type="radio" id="pants_Red" name="pants" value="1" />
...
```

Then in the event function you can easily construct the image filename by using.val():

```
var image_path = 'img'+$shirt.val()+$pants.val()+'.jpg';
```

Finally, set image file by using .attr()

```
$("#id-of-image-tag").attr("src",image_path);
```

You can see a combined example here http://jsfiddle.net/4bkngakw/
I make some changes though, such as using a div to display combined filename, and I also put a default value for both shirt and pants to prevent from undefined error.

Comment: Fantastic! So for that last line "$("#id-of-image-tag").attr("src",image_path);", I could do something like $("#img").attr("src"); and that would change the image source for an image tag with an ID of img, correct?

<img src="img11.jpg" id="img"> would set the default to img11.jpg and would change the image when the radio buttons are changed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not forget to choice and rate best answer.

Comment: $("#img").attr("src") will return the current src (as string), $("#img").attr("src",new-value) will change the src. That's how most of the functions in jQuery work: setter and getter share the same function name but with different parameters passed in. You're correct on using src="img11.jpg" as default value.

Comment: Understood. Youre making my life so much easier! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a *function* that maps and filters the *checked* radio buttons and renders the image related to their `index` like :

```
function renderImg(selectors) {
    var img = selectors.filter(function () {
        return $(this).is(":checked")
    }).map(function () {
        return $(this).index() + 1
    }).get();
    $("#result").html('<img src="images/image' + String(img[0]) + String(img[1]) + '.jpg" alt="" />')
}
```

Then run the *function* on page load and every time the radio buttons are `checked` like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var selectors = $("input[name=shirt], input[name=pants]");
    renderImg(selectors);
    selectors.on("change", function (e) {
        renderImg(selectors)
    })
}); // ready
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**Notice** the first *radio* buttons of each form are `checked`